# The right way to update after making changes to AWS Amplify Express Server?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, aws-amplify, amazon-gateway

When we make changes to a function in the express server, what is the right way to update using the AWS Amplify CLI?

For example I have a function like this:

```
app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {...}
```

And initially after the first push it works.

Then after editing and running push again I get this error:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network Error
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror] (xhr.js:83)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone-evergreen.js:1218)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41709)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1647)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at zone-evergreen.js:705
    at rejected (tslib.es6.js:72)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41731)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41709)
```

Upon getting that I tried running `amplify update api` and the `amplify push`, but I still get that error.

If I delete the API with `amplify remove api` and then `amplify push` and then recreate the API, it works.

Thoughts?

Also is there a way to troubleshoot the network error?

Answer (score 1):

OK - If not updating the path or adding a path then all that is needed is `amplify push`.  This works when adding more dependencies as well.

If we add more paths, then we need to run `amplify update` and then `amplify push`.